# What is the difference between intials cells and meristems cells?

Tags: plant-physiology, plant-anatomy, plant-perception

Generally plant tissues:

1. **meristems tissue:** meristems cells, apilal meristems, lateral meristems
2. **Non meristem tissue:** dermal tissue, vascular tissue, ground tissue

**my question:**

What is the difference between **intials** cells  and **meristems** cells? Are **intials** cells the same as **meristems** cells?

Comment: To contrast with meristem tissue; instead "non-meristem" tissue,  you may use the term "permanent tissue" (that is unable to divide normally untill de-differentiate at special conditions)

Answer (score 3):

Meristems are undifferentiated plant cells. There are two types:

1. apical mesistem that occurs at tips or branches and roots as well as buds which produces elongation, and
2. lateral meristem or cambium that produces lateral growth (stem thickening).

As cambium cells divide, cells toward the inside differentiate into xylem (wood) - these cells are 'xylem initials'. Cells toward the outside that eventually differentiate into phloem tissues (inner bark) and are 'phloem initials'.

One could similarly label apical meristem cells that are in the postion and/or process differentiating into leaves or flower organs as x-initials.

Comment: can you add some external/citable references to help back up your answer? We appreciate references so that others can read more and better understand the question/answer on BiologySE. Thanks for your efforts